# How to insert with a foreign key in the child table php

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables **`users`** And **`requests`**.  *Users table* has columns: `id`,  `username`, `password` and `town`. I can insert data in `users` successfully. `requests` table has: `id`, `user_id`, `product_name`,  `proposed_price` and `request_description`,  where `user_id` is a foreign key referencing to `id` from `users` table. The problem is that insert data fails in `requests` table which has `user_id` as a foreign key. I get an error:

> Undefined variable: user_id  and mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement on line :  $qry->bind_param("i", $user_id);

**This function is supposed to be used in insertion:**

```
public function  User_request ($product_name, $proposed_price, $request_description) {

     $qry = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = '$user_id' ");
     $qry->bind_param("i", $id);
     $result= $qry->execute();
     $user_id = $qry->num_rows();
     $qry->close();

    if($user_id > 0){

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO  requests (user_id, product_name, proposed_price, request_description) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)");

    $stmt->bind_param("sss",$user_id, $product_name, $proposed_price, $request_description);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE request_description = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $request_description);
        $stmt->execute();
        $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->close();

        return $user;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    }
}
```

**And below code calls above function:**

```
<?php

include './DbHandler.php';
$db = new DBHandler();

// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if ( isset($_POST['product_name']) && isset($_POST['proposed_price']) &&        isset($_POST['request_description']) ) {

// receiving the post params
$product_name = $_POST['product_name'];
$proposed_price =$_POST['proposed_price'];
$request_description =$_POST['request_description'];

    // create a new request
    $user = $db-User_request($product_name, $proposed_price,    $request_description);
    if ($user) {
        // user stored successfully
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        $response["user"]["username"] = $user["username"];
        $response["user"]["proposed_price"] = $user["proposed_price"];
        $response["user"]["request_description"] = $user["request_description"];

        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // user failed to store
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "oops error occured!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
   else {
     $response["error"] = TRUE;
      $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters are missing!";
     echo json_encode($response);
   }
  ?>
```

Comment: The answer is the same as this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39619591/how-to-get-last-auto-increment-value-as-foreign-key-to-another-table-in-php/43539268#43539268

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite `User_request()` function accordingly:

```
public function  User_request ($product_name, $proposed_price, $request_description) {

    $qry = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = ? ");
    $qry->bind_param("i", $user_id);
    $result= $qry->execute();
    $user_id = $qry->num_rows();
    $qry->close();

    if($user_id > 0){

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO requests (user_id, product_name, proposed_price, request_description) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)");

        $stmt->bind_param("isss", $user_id, $product_name, $proposed_price, $request_description);
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        // check for successful store
        if ($result) {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE request_description = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $request_description);
            $stmt->execute();
            $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
            $stmt->close();

            return $user;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:**
 You supposed to use placeholder `?` in prepare statement: `$this->conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = '$user_id' ");` in place of `'$user_id'`, since you have `$qry->bind_param("i", $user_id)`.
Similar error in `$stmt->bind_param("sss",$user_id, $product_name, $proposed_price, $request_description);`, replace `"sss"` with `"isss"`.

Comment: plz i don't see the difference

Comment: i updated  `$this->conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = '$user_id' ");`  to   `$this->conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = ?  ");`  and replaced  "sss" with "isss" but the error persists

Comment: @ the new error : is  store failure error  `oops error occured` i set in the part of code which calls **User_request function**

Comment: well, you have an undefined variable `$user_id` in your function, I suppose you should pass it as argument also to `User_request` function.

Comment: yes it might be true if `user_id` is an input values in my form, here if i define it in `user_request` function i will get an error in code that calls requests function telling me that some required parameters are missing .but what i need is the way i can get id value from users table and i directly  pass it into requests table as user_id

Comment: And also you are reassigning `$user_id = $qry->num_rows();` which has no relation at all with user_id.  The first part of your function until `if($user_id > 0)` statement is redundant, I think. Just try to understand your script and think over it's logic.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the string literal of '$user_id' here.

```
$qry = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = '$user_id' ");
```

This is probably not what you want. You are also using named placeholders that are nowhere to be found in your query. I suggest reviewing the PDO docs.